# Is AFHTTPClient Thread Safe?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

The AFNetworking documentation suggests that a common (singleton) subclass of `AFHTTPClient` is created per web service.  In my application, the web service may be accessed from multiple background worker threads.  Can that singleton be called safely from multiple threads?

Or, more basically, can a single instance of a `AFHTTPClient` be used safely from multiple threads, or should there be one per thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AFHTTPClient operations are self-contained. As AFHTTPClient uses NSOperationQueue internally  and NSOperationQueue documentation says :

> It is safe to use a single NSOperationQueue object from multiple
>   threads without creating additional locks to synchronize access to
>   that object.

It should be safe to use one instance of a AFHTTPClient from multiple threads if each AFHTTPClient operation is managed by one thread.

Comment: That's more or less what I was thinking, just hoping to get some validation from the community since its not explicitly stated anywhere as far as I can tell.  Thanks for the feedback!